# What is use of contextconfiglocation in web.xml of Spring-based web-app?

Tags: xml, spring, context-configuration

In Spring, what is purpose of `ContextConfigLocation` and also `InternalResourceViewResolver`? I did't get the purpose of these classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`contexConficLocation` is using in `web.xml` file.
This purpose is override the acctual or default XML file in user wish.
It is comeing under the `<contex-param>` tag, for example

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/spring-config.xml,WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

`InternalResourceViewResolver` using inside `servlet.xml` file  it is comeing under the `viewResolver` bean.

Example

```xml
<beans>
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="WEB-INF/view/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```